# Negative amounts on crystal report not showing up when one of the formula values is zero

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a report with a formula field that calculates the difference between two fields:
Original Contract         Change Orders               Current Contract
50,000                    20,000                      70,000
35,000                   -10,000                      25,000

Then I have a record that has 0 for current contract 
88,500                                                0

The calculated field for change orders is current contract - original contract.  When the current contract is 0 the number does not display on the report for the change orders.

Any ideas what might be causing this?  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do would be to check the formatting of the field... Right click the field in question on your report -> hit "Format Field" -> go to the "Number" tab -> then hit the "Customize" button

Ensure the "Suppress if Zero" box is not checked. Also, ensure there are no conflicting rules set in the "Show Zero Values as:" field

[image: CR snapshot]

Your title also mentions negative values... are those missing as well? Could you try to rephrase your question, being as detailed as possible?